# Ordering the writes of different Pcollections outputs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wrote a ParDo function that returns multiple side outputs. 
Although PCollections elements are unordered, I'd like to write these different types of Pcollections sequentially.
Does the Beam SDK support this feature?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to order the processing of each of those outputs in the subsequent steps? If so, you could potentially use the [Wait transform](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.7.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html).

So for a PCollectionTuple "results" with three tuple tags (ONE, TWO and THREE).

```
results.get(THREE)
  .apply(Wait.on(results.get(TWO))
                 .apply(Wait.on(results.get(ONE)
                                .apply(new ProcessOne()))
                 .apply(new ProcessTwo())
  .apply(new ProcessThree());
```

This should allow ONE to be processed before TWO followed by THREE.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the problem is that the write() method of a sink returns a PDone and not a PCollection. 

In this case, I would need to write in a ParDo function. However, I'm not even sure if there is an example of how to do that in a reliable way. Do you know?